# How I can represent this relation in class diagram?

Tags: java, uml, relationship, class-diagram

I made a Java application where each class performs a processing and at the end it creates an instance of another class. It also calls a method of this class and passes results to it in the parameters of the method like this:

```
public class Matrix{
     public double CalculerMinimum()
     {
        ....
           if ((result < min)) {
                        min = result;
               }
       

            Liste lis  = new Liste();
            lis.getFile(min);
         return min;
     }
 }
```

```
public class Liste{
     public string getFile(double min)
     {
        ....
           
         return lien;
     }
}
```

What is the relationship between classes? how I can represent that with a class diagram?

Comment: Take a look into `interaction diagrams` e.g https://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_interaction_diagram.htm

Comment: Class diagrams show static information. You are talking about behavior. Which of both are you after?

Comment: @qwerty_so I'm looking for the class diagram, can we represent a dependency relationship between these two classes saying that the List class depends on the Matrix class and we represent this with a discontinuous arrow in class diagram ?

Comment: your code is invalid, how can you have `Liste lis  = new Liste(); lis.getFile(min);` after `return min;` ?

Comment: @bruno Thanks for the comment. I'll change that.

Comment: sorry to insist but `Liste lis  = new Liste();` is also invalid because *lis* is a *Liste* but `new Liste` return  a `List*` probably you just wanted `Liste lis;` ? (if you really want `Liste * lis  = new Liste();`so `lis->getFile(min);` please also add `delete lis;` to avoid a memoty leak, but tu allocate in the heap in that case is useless and expensive for nothing)

Answer (score 3):

Your `Matrix` class creates and uses the `Liste` class.  This is called a [dependency](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html?context=class-diagrams). You can represent it in a class-diagram with a dotted arrow and `«use»` and/or `«create»`.

Your code shows no kind of [association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html?context=class-diagrams) nor [generalization](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html?context=class-diagrams). The fact that a `Liste` is used in the implementation of an operation is [not sufficient to make an association](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63401925/3723423): this `Liste` is local and encapsulated in the operation; there is no conceptual association between the two classes themselves (and you could imagine an implementation of `CalculerMinimum()` that doesn't use any `Liste`).

What you cannot represent in the class-diagram is the dynamic of the behavior.  If you're interested in the dynamics you'd need to use a [behavior diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html).

Comment: so we can represent all the class diagram with only dependency relationships

Comment: @Cissus Yes, if it's the case there is no problem doing so.

Comment: @Cissus your may be, but not all in general

Comment: Indeed.  THe fact that a `Liste` is used in the implementation of an operation is not sufficient to make this relation an association: this list is local and encapsulated in the operation. There is no conceptual association between the two classes themselves, and you could imagine an implementation of `CalculerMinimum()` that doesn't use any `liste`