# Class diagram representation of my java swing project

Tags: java, swing, uml, diagram, class-diagram

`JFrame1` and `JFrame2` are both classes I wrote that extend `javax.swing.JFrame`.

There is a button (a `JButton`) located in `JFrame1` and I registered a `MouseClicked` event with it. When I click the button on `JFrame1`, it closes and `JFrame2` is visible. (They don't have anything that links them other than `JFrame2.setVisible(true)`)

So, should there be a relationship (association, aggregation, composition, dependency,...) between these two classes in my class diagram, and if yes, which relatioship?

Comment: [How to use Buttons, Check Boxes and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I asked.

Comment: I know. Just my way of letting you know that you should register an `ActionListener` with a `JButton` and not a `MouseListener` because clicking a `JButton` with the mouse is not the only way to activate the `JButton`. For example, if the `JButton` has keyboard focus, pressing the space bar on the computer keyboard will activate the `JButton`. And if the `JButton` is the default button, pressing <ENTER> will also activate the button, even if it does not have keyboard focus. Besides which, a _Swing_ application should have one `JFrame` only. Use `javax.swing.JDialog` instead of another `JFrame`

Answer (score 1):

A class diagram represents a [structural view](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_domains/structuraldiagrams.html) of your classes.

So if one class just happens to use the other in its implementation or during the execution, it’s [not sufficient to make an association](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62562583/3723423). So you could leave them completely separate in the diagram.

Nevertheless, the two classes are not fully independent either. `JFrame1` needs `JFrame2`. It’s not mandatory, but you could represent this as a [usage dependency](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-soft-arch/9.7.0?topic=diagrams-dependency-relationships) (a dotted arrow from 1 to 2, with an explicit  `«use»`)