# Can Python pyreverse generate UML diagram for functions?

Tags: python, uml, pylint, class-diagram, pyreverse

[pyreverse](https://pypi.org/project/pyreverse/) is a great tool to generate UML diagram from Python codes. However, I found it cannot identify all the classes that has been used within a function. I take the following example to illustrate my point:

```
class ClassA(object):
   def __init__(self):
         pass
class ClassB(object):
   def __init__(self):
         pass
class ClassC(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.object_b = ClassB() 
   def perform():
      object_a = ClassA()
```

If we use pyreverse to generate class diagram, it is clear that we can see `ClassB` is a component within `ClassC`. However, it cannot generate the relationship with `ClassA`, which is used in its function `perform`. Is there any way for pyreverse to retrieve the relationship between `ClassC` and `ClassA`?

Comment: I don't know pyreverse, but code analysis is usually not part of these tools. And unfortunately this object creation is runtime Python-wise. It's an interpreted language. Those C-like languages have headers where these associations could be found. I guess you need to send a feature request to the pyreverse developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is the [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690920/3723423) of `object_a`: it is a local variable of the function and not an instance variable. The relationship of C with A is therefore not structural. Hence, it is [not an UML association](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62562583/3723423) (nor aggregation, nor composition).

At best, we could say there is a usage dependency from C to A. But this usage is specific to the implementation and not necessarily meant by design.

I’m not a Python expert, but if pyreverse is able to spot the right relation with `object_b`, and if you’d make `object_a` an instance variable with `self.object_a` in the assignment, you can hope to get the result that you expected.

**Edit:  Experimental verification**

If the class C is corrected as explained:

```
class ClassC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.object_b = ClassB()
    def perform(self):
        self.object_a = ClassA()
```

pyreverse generates indeed the right result as expected:

[image]

For a human reader, it's easy to miss a property.  This is why pylint issues a warning on this code:

```
W0201: Attribute 'object_a' defined outside __init__ (attribute-defined-outside-init)
```

Note also that if you define a [(static) class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68645/3723423) instead of an instance variable, pyreverse does not show it with an underlined name.  The reason is probably, because it's not uncommon to hide a class variable with an instance variable of the same name.